# No WiFi option in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, 19.10

I know that this type of question has been asked before, but those solutions didn't work for me. I have recently installed Ubuntu 19.10 by removing Windows 10. After the installation, I was surprised to find that there is no WiFi option at all in the settings.
[image]

I have also checked the **Network** group, WiFi option was not there either.
[image]

Luckily, I am able to connect to internet through USB tethering on my Android phone.
Here is the output of `lsusb` command :

```
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

Here is the output of `lshw` command (only the WiFi dongle part):

```
*-usb:1 UNCLAIMED
                      description: Generic USB device
                      product: 802.11n
                      vendor: Realtek
                      physical id: 4
                      bus info: usb@2:1.4
                      version: 0.00
                      serial: 00E0202C7613
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

How to bring the WiFi option? Please ask if more information are needed.

Comment: There is no general solution "to fix Wi-Fi". "those solutions didn't work for me". Whusch solutions did you try that didn't work? You didn't provide information about your hardware. Are you using a USB dongle?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Pilot6. The link that you provided indeed worked for me. Perhaps I didn't knew that the model of my adapter was **rtl8188fu**, that's why I didn't dared to try it before.